# Odd object interaction with buttons, focusable property doing something strange

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
 private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                if (shipPosition < right)
                {
                    x = x + 10;
                    shipPosition = shipPosition + 10;
                    ship.Margin = new Thickness(shipPosition, y, 0, 0);
                }
            }
         }

   XAML - KeyDown="Page_KeyDown"
```

I have a rectangle named ship, and above is the function to move it, to be executed on right or left arrow key button press. For some reason, this doesn't work. The "KeyDown="Page_KeyDown"" is the xaml that links the button press with the event. There is another grid containing buttons that moves every time a timer ticks, and when I click on a button and highlight it, then press the arrow keys, the ship starts to move, with the highlighted button being changed as well. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

**Update:** I removed the is focusable property on the buttons, and that then stopped ship movement all together. So I think it is something to do with the changing of focus on buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Keyboard.AddKeyDownHandler(this, Page_KeyDown);
```

Put it in the appropriate method of your control (constructor, initialized, ...)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Keyboard.AddKeyDownHandler(this, Page_KeyDown);
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to change much, but it would solve the problem of where to put the key down declaration. I removed the is focusable property of all the buttons and this stopped the ship moving altogether. Must be something to do with the changing of focus on the buttons...